# How to execute a complicated external command from within python?

Tags: python, bash, command, subprocess, external

I wonder how to execute a complicated external command from within python?

It works well in linux bash command line:
$ mysqldump --single-transaction -u myusername -pmypassword mydb mytable > mytable.sql

But it doesn't work from within python code:
subprocess.call(['mysqldump' '--single-transaction' '-u myusername' '-pmypasword' 'mydb' 'mytable' '>' 'mytable.sql'])

What's wrong with my python code?

Or I have to use os.system() ??

Please tell me how it can work from within python code, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `>` isn't a command-line argument to the program. `>`, in this context, is actually a shell output redirection operator. It gets processed by the shell itself, not by the `mysqldump` program.

Python's `subprocess` knows nothing about the shell, so it can't understand shell operators such as `>`. It just tries to give `>` and `mytable.sql` to `mysqldump` as arguments, which `mysqldump` also does not understand, causing an error.

What you need to do is set up your subprocess to redirect its output. The way to do that in Python is:

```
with open('mytable.sql', 'w') as f:
  subprocess.call(['mysqldump',
                   '--single-transaction', 
                   '-u',
                   'myusername',
                   '-pmypasword', 
                   'mydb',
                   'mytable'], stdout=f)
```

The `stdout` argument to `subprocess.call` allows you to direct your subprocess's output wherever you like, just as the `>` shell operator does.

Comment: Sir, your solution is totally correct, thank you from heart!

Comment: I'm glad to help! If my answer has been helpful, please upvote and accept it :)

Comment: Hi Pedro, I tried upvoting quite a few times, but always ended up with failures, weird! Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Gotcha, stackoverflow says that my vote will be recorded but not displayed publicly because I am a newbie here, my reputation value is less than 15 points. INTERESTING!

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be a syntax error,

```
subprocess.call(['mysqldump' '--single-transaction' '-u' 'myusername' '-pmypasword' 'mydb' 'mytable' '>' 'mytable.sql'])
```

Missing the `'-u' 'myusername'` quote separation.

Also, `subprocess.run` replaces `subprocess.call` in version >= 3.5.  Check [python subprocess.call API deprecation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html?highlight=subprocess#call-function-trio)
This should work for you.

Comment: No, after correcting this typo, it still doesn't work

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work, my error.  Pedro is correct with the redirect to `stdout`.  The deprecated `subprocess.call` and typo still applies.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of executing complicated external command from within python:

https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-shell

Azure-shell is an iteractive Azure CLI 2.0 commandline interface that it internally us subprocess

```
import subprocess
full_cmd = "external command"
p = subprocess.Popen(full_cmd, shell=True, env=self._env)
p.communicate()
```

An external command here is az command (azure-cli 2.0) which has lots of commands options and parameters, which thus can be very complicated. Therefore, azure-shell support auto-completion of both command options and parameters for the azure-cli that helps its users to save time for checking azure cli command reference or typing 'az  -h'. To achieve the auto-completion capabilities, it leverage python prompt toolkit

https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit

Hope it would help

Comment: I don't want to import more complicated thing for this simple requirement, os.system() is much easier and it's a built-in function. Thanks anyway.